# Stopwatch and resetting time after button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently learning how to work with the stopwatch attribute in C#. I have a `button1` that starts the stopwatch. I would like to reset the time to 0 and start over again after the second click and so forth on. How would I be able to reset stopwatch timer after each consecutive button click?

**Code**

```
namespace stopwatch
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    
        }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            sw.Start();   
            TimeSpan x = sw.Elapsed;
            textBox1.Text = x.ToString();                   
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect that `x` is greater than 0? Apart from that, `Stopwatch` has a method [`Reset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.reset.aspx) which does what you're looking for.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yet for the second click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Stopwatch.StartNew()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew.aspx)

Try this piece of code snippet instead:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    // ... do something ...

    sw.Stop();

    textBox1.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
}
```

Comment: -1 It seems not correct for me considering following requirements `I would like to reset the time to 0 and start over again after the second click and so forth on.`. This code snipped will leave Stopwatch in stopped state after a button click and he needs reset to 0 and start it again. BTW Why you need a new instance of `Stopwatch` each time?

Comment: I agree with this point of view: [See on Meta - To Downvote or Not to Downvote…or to Wait?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112664). basically _I think_ your answer is not correct so you have to provide some arguments or correct it otherwise SO would not be such a helpful community. And nothign personal, I also got many downvotes for incorrect or even just confusing answers, I will remove my downvote just please spend more time and check whether your answer correct, also it is a case that question is confusing

Comment: Requirement was - `I would like to reset the time to 0 and start over again after the second click and so forth on`, but in your case stopwatch will be stopped after a button click because of `sw.Stop()`, is it clear now? So `How would I be able to reset stopwatch timer after each consecutive button click` - so he needs resetting a stopwatch not stopping it, so after each button click SW just start counts from 0

Comment: Ok and at the end of buttonClick handler you put `sw.Stop()` which leaves SW in stopped state!

Comment: If StartNew is such a costly method then why this is there in the library. Its simply the inability of the developers of Microsoft to put it there. In the end its a useless argumentation.

Comment: Let's forget about a cost of `StartNew()` this is an other question and does not make any difference in a code snippet logic. StartNew() just allows you in one line of a code doing `var sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start();` and nothing more, thsi is like a `Restart()` which perfectly does `sw.Reset(); sw.Start()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sw.Stop();
    TimeSpan x = sw.Elapsed;
    textBox1.Text = x.ToString();

    // >= .NET 4
    sw.Restart();    

    // >=.NET 2.0
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();                   
}
```

Comment: This will always return no time elapsed... not the time elapsed since the last click

Comment: Surely you would want the `Restart` *after* you display the value...?

Comment: Surely yes, this is so obvious :) I've just update my answer, I do not use `StartNew()` since it more costly since creates a new insatnce of a Stopwatch

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            sw.Stop();

            TimeSpan x = sw.Elapsed;

            textBox1.Text = x.ToString();

            sw.Restart();
     }
```